# Rename item list for python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of items

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

or any other list of 16 items.

How to replace the first 12 items with `'#'`?

Comment: Look up list slicing.

Comment: mulitple way to achieve this, you can use index, go with a loop or a lambda function...

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

lst[:12] = "#" * 12
print(lst)
```

Prints:

```
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing and concatenation:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16] 
print(['#'] * 12 + arr[12:])
```

Output:

```
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

The expression

```
['#'] * 12 + arr[12:]
```

simply takes `['#']`, multiplies it with `12` to make it

```
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']
```

and concatenates it with the element of `arr` after the 12th element.

Comment: To OP: recognise the difference between this and the answer from @Andrej Kesley : this solution creates a new list, so `arr` remains unchanged. The other solution modifies `lst` in-place